# Residencias de/para personas mayores

Tags: gramática

Quisiera saber la diferencia de significado entre “[residencias de personas mayores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residencia_de_personas_mayores)” y “[residencias para personas mayores](https://medlineplus.gov/spanish/nursinghomes.html)”. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La preposición "de" es una de las más versátiles del idioma y puede expresar muchos significados que también se pueden transmitir a través de otras preposiciones más específicas.

Tanto "residencias de personas mayores" como "residencias para personas mayores" son correctos y, no habiendo diferencia de significado, resultan intercambiables. Mientras que el primero transmite un sentido de pertenencia, el segundo expresa finalidad.

Un ejemplo similar sería "escuela de ciegos" y "escuela para ciegos".

Otro ejemplo que se me ocurre, pero con una preposición diferente para reemplazar a "de", es "viaje de negocios" y "viaje por negocios": la preposición "por" es más específica por cuanto expresa causalidad (el motivo del viaje), pero ambas frases son correctas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!